# How to get the most frequent character within a character string?

Tags: r, string

Suppose the next character string:

```
test_string <- "A A B B C C C H I"
```

Is there any way to extract the most frequent value within `test_string`?

Something like:

```
extract_most_frequent_character(test_string)
```

Output:

```
#C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `scan` to read the string as a vector of individual elements by splitting at the space, get the frequency count with `table`, return the named index that have the max count (`which.count`), get its `name`

```
extract_most_frequent_character <- function(x) {
     names(which.max(table(scan(text = x, what = '', quiet = TRUE))))
}
```

-testing

```
extract_most_frequent_character(test_string)
[1] "C"
```

---

Or with `strsplit`

```
extract_most_frequent_character <- function(x) {
     names(which.max(table(unlist(strsplit(x, "\\s+")))))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility involving `stringr` could be:

```
names(which.max(table(str_extract_all(test_string, "[A-Z]", simplify = TRUE))))

[1] "C"
```

Or marginally shorter:

```
names(which.max(table(str_extract_all(test_string, "[A-Z]")[[1]])))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R option (not as elegant as [@akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673981/12158757))

```
> intToUtf8(names(which.max(table(utf8ToInt(gsub("\\s", "", test_string))))))
[1] "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution using `stringr` package, `table` and `which`:

```
library(stringr)
test_string <- str_split(test_string, " ")

test_string <- table(test_string)

names(test_string)[which.max(test_string)]

[1] "C"
```